# Compile together files from github

Tags: javascript, node.js, github

I am new to Node.js and I am looking for guidance on how to compile together different .md files.

I downloaded [this repository](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/tree/master/Docs) and would like to join/merge/compile-together all `.md` files. So I would like to get one single file with the content of each of the individual files so that I can have a new .md file with all the content inside.

This is what I was thinking about...

```
var docsdir = '../Docs/';
var filesArray = fs.readdir(docsdir, function(err,files){
    if (err) console.error(err);
    // missing how to check if file is a directory
    return files;
}
var newFile;
for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    fs.readFile(files[i], function read(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        newFile = newFile + data;
    });     
}
fs.writeFile('wholeDocs', newFile)
```

THe directory structure is in this example:

```
+
|-Docs
   |
   |-folder1
   |    |
   |    |-file1.md
   |
   |
   |-folder2
   |    |
   |    |-file3.md

etc...
```

Comment: Concatenating filenames isn't going to get you much!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, thank you for looking at this. I understand that, but posted that "javascript child thinking" because that is what my knowledge today allows me to. ʘ‿ʘ Can you point me in a better way?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, added a `fs.readFile()` on my post to share where my thinking/knowledge is for stage.

Comment: It really depends on your requirements. If simple concatenation of the text files is enough, then simply do that. Otherwise you'll have to explain more about the result you're seeking.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, ok. Sorry if I was not not clear... I want to join the content of the `.md` files so that I can have a new `.md` file with all the content inside.

Comment: And I'm asking you to define that more precisely!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, aha... sorry again. The goal is to export a new file where I can read all the content from the combined files. Because its different files of the same project it would be great to have all those documentation files in one big file. Keeping all format, all text of .md files like [this](https://raw.github.com/mootools/mootools-core/master/Docs/Core/Core.md) or [this](https://raw.github.com/mootools/mootools-core/master/Docs/Class/Class.md) in one bigger file.

Comment: So, it's not basic concatenation, but concatenation with the addition of some headings in between each file's text. Now you need to explain, precisely, the output you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is offline processing so you can use fs.Sync() to do the job that easier than async function.

Note that async is a must if you write web app, async help avoid app blocking.

You also need to known about recursive.

You can learn from code below:

```
var fs = require('fs'), path = require('path');
function findAllFile(dir, ext) {
    var ret = [];
    function findOneLevel(dir) {
        fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(function(file) {
            var name = path.join(dir, file);
            var stat = fs.statSync(name);
            if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                findOneLevel(name);
            } else if (stat.isFile() && path.extname(name).toLowerCase() === ext) {
                ret.push(name);
            }
        });
    }
    findOneLevel(dir);
    return ret;
}
function concatAllMd(dir, outFile) {
    var contents = [];
    findAllFile(dir, '.md').forEach(function(file) {
        contents.push(fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8'));
    })
    fs.writeFileSync(outFile, contents.join('\n'));
}

// use
concatAllMd('Docs', 'output.md');
```